# Angular 4: use Service in a validator function

Tags: angular

I want to use a Service in a form-validation function.

I have a file for the service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Apollo } from 'apollo-angular';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(private apollo: Apollo) {}

  test() {
    return "test"
  }
}
```

and a file for the validator function

```
import { AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import { AuthService } from './../../auth/services/auth.service'

export function UsernameValidator(control: AbstractControl) {
  let test = AuthService.test(control.value)
  if (test !== "test") {
    return of(null)
  } else {
    return of( { validName: { message: "username cannot be test" } })
  }
}
```

my problem is, that the validator function isnt aware of the service and therefor says

> Property 'test' does not exist on type 'typeof AuthService'

Can anyone explain to me, how to make the validator function aware of the service or how to inject the service or instantiate it correctly?

Comment: You can make `UsernameValidator` a service class with a `validate` (or whatever name) method, inject the validator and pass `this.userNameValidator.validate.bind(this.userNameValidator)` to the control as validator. When the validator is a service it can just inject other services.

Comment: thx, i did it that way